# write big blocks to file with fwrite() (e.g. 1000000000)

Tags: c, fwrite

I am attempting to write blocks with `fwrite()`. At this point the largest block I could write was 100000000 (it is probably a bit higher than that...I did not try..). I cannot write a block with the size 1000000000 the outputfile is 0 Byte.

Is there any possibilty to write blocks like e.g. 1000000000 and greater?

I am using `uint64_t` to store these great numbers.

Thank you in advance!

*Code from pastebin in comment: -zw*

```
      char * pEnd;
        uint64_t uintBlockSize=strtoull(chBlockSize, &pEnd, 10);
        uint64_t uintBlockCount=strtoull(chBlockCount, &pEnd, 10);

        char * content=(char *) malloc(uintBlockSize*uintBlockCount);





        /*
        Create vfs.structure
        */
        FILE *storeFile;
        storeFile = fopen (chStoreFile, "w");
        if (storeFile!=NULL)
        {
            uint64_t i=uintBlockCount;

            size_t check;

            /*
                Fill storeFile with empty Blocks
            */
            while (i!=0)
            {
                fwrite(content,uintBlockSize, 1, storeFile);
                i--;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to write so much data with a single block?

Comment: well i got the exercise to write files without limitations in blocksize or blockcount so u call the programm with parameters ./program 10000000000 20  and it should write 20 blocks with the size given.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: http://gw.gd/DW9Y  i think this is the important part

Comment: Are you compiling for 64-bit? Because no matter what integer type you use to store your block size the `fwrite` call accepts `size_t` as block size and it is only 32 bits on 32-bit binaries by default.

Comment: Check the status of the file after the write with ferror(). Maybe also read and utilize this man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_ferror - this might describe why exactly it does not work. In 32 bits theoretically there should not be problems until 2^31-1 which is more than 2 times more than 1000000000 (1 billion).

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice, i am compiling for 32-bit, ofcourse!

Comment: (1) Is the use of `fwrite` a hard requirement? This task will be easier with the lower-level [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).  (2) Try placing `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` at the very top of the file (above all `#include`s).

Comment: write could be an alternative but i am not allowed to use  <unistd.h>. 
what is this `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` for?

Comment: You call `malloc` with an argument of `uintBlockSize*uintBlockCount`. First, confirm that `uintBlockSize*uintBlockCount` doesn't overflow a `size_t`; on your system, the maximum value for `size_t` is probably 2**32-1. And you *must* check whether `malloc()` returned a null pointer. Even for a value of `1000000000` (1 billion, which easily fits in 32 bits), your system might not let you allocate that much memory.

Comment: You need to be very specific about the values you're using, and count the zeros for us. It's very hard to tell at a glance whether 1000000000 is one billion or ten billion, and whether *you* typed what you mean to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assuming that the type used in your C library to represent the size of objects and index memory (`size_t`) can hold the same range of values as `uint64_t`. This may not be the case!

`fwrite`'s [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) indicates that you can use the function to write blocks whose size is limited by the `size_t` type. If you're on a 32bit system, the block size value passed to `fwrite` will be cast from `uint64_t` to whatever the library's `size_t` is (`uint32_t`, for example, in which case a very large value will have its most significant digits lost).

Comment: thank you for that answer! so is there any other function as fwrite() to do what i want to do?

Comment: No: `fwrite()` or the underlying `write()` system call are both limited by using `size_t` for the size argument.  Hence, on a 32-bit system, you can't write 4 GiB blocks (but you can write 4 GiB - 1 byte blocks if you so choose).

Comment: The OP says it fails to work with a size of 1000000000. That's one billion, and it fits easily in 32 bits. It's not a problem with the limits of a 32-bit `size_t`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, you're right. The only other thing I can think of off-the-bat is that OP added an extra zero (perhaps accidentally) on the command line. Quoting from a comment he made to his original post, he's invoking the program with: `./program 10000000000 20`. 10^10 will not fit in 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I have had fwrite fail with a block >64MB compiled with gcc 4.1.2 on CentOS 5.3
I had to chop it up into smaller pieces.
I also had fread() fail for >64MB blocks on the same setup.

This seems to have been fixed in later Linux environments, e.g. Ubuntu 12.04.